# How to convert txt file data to json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to convert txt file to json using fs methods it is throwing an error `omething is wrong TypeError: data.split is not a function` what is implemented wrong here

index.js

```
 try {
    let data = await fs.readFileSync(path.join(filePath));
    const obj = {
      User: "",
      User: Location: "",
      Company Name: "",
      Notes: " "
  };
    const content = [];
    data.split("\n").map((line) => {   
          if (line.startsWith("User:")) {
              obj.title = line.substring(6);
          } else if (line.startsWith("Company Name:")) {
            obj.title = line.substring(6);
          } else if (line.startsWith("User Location:")) {
            obj.tags = line.substring(4).split(",");
          } else if (line.startsWith("Notes:")) {
            obj.tags = line.substring(4).split(",");
          }   else {
                content.push(line);
            }
    });
    obj.content = content.join("\n");
    const finalres = fs.writeFileSync("output.json", JSON.stringify(obj));
    console.log("Final>>>>>>", finalres);
    res.send(finalres);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("something is wrong", e);
  }
```

doc.txt

```
User: Account Admin

User Location:  New York, NY

Company Name: WeightWatcher

Notes:  Enabling growth through experimentation and analysis to 
      build a world-class onboarding experience
     Building and managing monitoring, configuration, control 
     plane, and operational services to allow
```

Comment: so what is data? `console.log(data)`

Comment: @epascarello data is printed as buffer [0] DATA <Buffer 4a 6f 62 20 54 69 74 6c 65

Comment: `data..toString().split()`

Comment: made the change now its printing  Final>>>>>> undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

```
 await fs.readFileSync(path.join(filePath));
```

`readFileSync` does not return promise. fix it by deleting the `await`. it is a `Sync` method so it will wait until it finished.

also `readFileSync` will return Buffer. you can convert the buffer to a string or add the option like this :

```
fs.readFileSync(path.join(filePath),{encoding:'utf8'});
```

---

also fix the object to a valid json notation:

```
    const obj = {
      User: "",
      "User Location": "",
      "Company Name": "",
      Notes: ""
  };
```

Comment: this is retuning now string however final obj is still printing [0] Final>>>>>> undefined

Comment: @hussain because that how it works. it returns `undefined`. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options

Comment: yes, `writeFileSync` does not return the contents of the file.